# Django - Export to Excel and render to template

Tags: django, forms, excel, templates, export

Changed Question: 5/5/12 2:34pm (PST)

I would like to know if it is possible to render a template from form POST data and in that template, provide a button/link to an Excel spreadsheet of the same POST data that was used in the template.

I have made an Excel download using the POST, and I have rendered a template using the POST, but I would like the following to happen with the form's Submit button is pushed:
1. Send the information from the view to template, have the template render the information, in the template have a button/link that when clicked, a window pops up asking the user if they want to Open/Save the .XLS file.

The code I am using to do each follows:
1 Render template in new URL
`return render_to_response('report/result.html', {long dictionary}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

2 Export as .XLS file using template:
`response2 = render_to_response('report/result.html', {long dictionary}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
`filename = "ToolboxReport%s.xls" % (datetime.now())`
`response2['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename`
`response2['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'`
`return response2`

Here is my intended order:
1. At Options page: select options, click Generate Report button
2. At Results page: display information, display button/link to download this info as .XLS
3. (Optional) Clicks download button: Open/Save option appears to download the same information as .XLS

I can't seem to get the POST data from the Options page to be used in both the Results page and the .XLS download.

Comment: So you want to serve some file AND at the same show html page? I'm not sure this is possible. May be you want a page with data, and a link to (on this page) to the data in xls format?

Comment: That would work also :) That is what I'm currently trying to do actually, but I am stuck on this as well :(

Comment: I'd consider using django-tablib (https://github.com/joshourisman/django-tablib) for your data conversions (queryset to excel). It even features generic views that allow you to save/export your querysets/datasets as excel sheets.

Comment: I have my excel documents generating just how I want them, I just need to figure out how to display the results in html format, and also provide a download for the excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use two different buttons on my forms, one for *listing the results* and one for *exporting them to excel*.

In the form template:

```
<input type="submit" name="list" value="List Results" />
<input type="submit" name="excel" value="Export to Excel" />
```

And in my view function:

```
# process your post data here...

# end processing your post data
if request.REQUEST.get('excel'): 
    # excel button clicked
    result = '<your content result here>'
    response = http.HttpResponse(result.encode("<encoding>", 'ignore'), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=<charset>')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="reports.csv"'
    response['Expires'] = "Mon, 26 Jul 2013 05:00:00 GMT"
    return response
elif request.REQUEST.get('list'):
    # List button clicked
    return render_to_response(<some render param here>, <some context>, <etc>)
```

Comment: Forgot I never chose an answer to my question. I found this solution in another stackoverflow post. Since I chose to do the same thing as your solution, FallenAngel, you get the best answer!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to build a form with hidden input tags containing the information you got from the previous post and a submit button.
Add an additional parameter to tell your view you want to download.

Comment: I tried that also, but my lists that I was passing were getting messed up. (I think they were turning into lists of lists, and I gave up after an hour or so of trying to get it working).